# i have a problem with duplicate rows in python

Tags: python, pandas

i want  to Remove duplicate data in a rows from data frame python without affecting the shape of the DataFrame

i tried already this cods but i could not bring the year column to the now dataframe

any help thanks

```html
dicpn = dict()

for value in ss.Country.unique():
    if len(ss.loc[(ss.Country == value) & ss.Country.duplicated(keep=False)]) > 0:
        all_values = ss.loc[(ss.Country == value) & ss.Country.duplicated(keep=False), 'Count'].tolist()
        dicpn[value] = all_values
    elif len(ss.loc[(ss.Country == value) & ss.Country.duplicated(keep=False)]) == 0:
        dicpn[value] = ss.loc[(ss.Country== value), 'Count'].tolist()

# make a new dataframe
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['landen', 'Count'])
df2.landen = list(dicpn.keys())
df2.Count = list(dicpn.values())
```

```html
    landen  Count
0   Argentina   [6, 15, 10, 4, 11, 1, 13, 7, 8, 1, 2, 2, 22, 3...
1   Australia   [2, 1, 2230, 1, 3, 1, 5, 55, 38, 48, 9, 1, 2, ...
2   Belgium [1289, 1, 1620, 3, 8, 28, 13, 37, 2, 1, 560, 3...
3   Canada  [1, 5, 230, 3, 4, 9, 3, 1, 1376, 159, 11, 44, ...
4   China   [168, 12, 1, 114, 5, 8961, 1, 33, 4, 3, 23, 21...
5   Denmark [11, 20, 4, 2, 479, 140, 5, 53, 9, 2, 12, 16, ...
```

```
    Country PublishYear Count
8   Argentina   2003    6
9   Argentina   2014    15
10  Argentina   2010    10
11  Argentina   2015    4
12  Argentina   2014    11
... ... ... ...
254169  United States   2004    2
254170  United States   2004    955
254171  United States   2003    10
254172  United States   2015    16
254173  United States   2012    259
```

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnFQL.png)